# Nginx ignoring server blocks and works only with one HTTPS SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have got 10 domains that need to be working on 80;
I user server_name _ wildcard

each domain is a folder like this 
/var/www/DOMAINNAME1.org
/var/www/DOMAINNAME2.com

And I've got domain SSLDomain.org that needs to be working on 443 ssl
and all incoming traffic from port 80 to SSLDomain.org should be going to SSLDomain.org:443 https

nginx ignores wildcard and all domains are using SSLDomain.org SSL certificate :(
and all domains are redirected to https

Comment: server{
listen 443 ssl;
server_name SSLDOMAIN.org;
ssl on;
ssl_certificate /var/www/SSLDOMAIN.org/ssl/SSLDOMAIN.org.bundle.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /var/www/SSLDOMAIN.org/ssl/SSLDOMAIN.org.key;
    server_name_in_redirect off;

    if ($host ~* ^(.*\..*)$) {
        set $domain $host;
    }

    if ($host ~* ^(.*)\.(.*\..*)$) {
        set $domain $2;
    }



    root /var/www/$domain;
;;;;;

server {
listen 80;


    server_name _;
    server_name_in_redirect off;

    if ($host ~* ^(.*\..*)$) {
        set $domain $host;

Comment: If you need to add information to your question, use edit rather than comments. Do you have [HTTP Strict Transport Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) with the `includeSubDomains` option on the parent domain?